# Performance of n-section root finding algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, benchmarking, numerical-methods

I wrote a n-section algorithm for finding roots of a function. The working principle is exactly the same as is bisection method, only the range is divided into *N* equal parts instead. This is my C code:

```
/*
    Compile with: clang -O3 -o nsect nsect.c -Wall -DCOUNT=5000000 -DNSECT=? -funroll-loops
*/

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define N 6

#ifndef COUNT
#error COUNT not defined!
#endif

#ifndef NSECT
#define NSECT 2
#endif

float polynomial[N];
float horner( const float poly[N], float x )
{
    float val = poly[N-1];
    for ( int i = N - 2; i >= 0; i-- )
        val = poly[i] + x * val;
    return val;
}

float f( float x )
{
    return horner( polynomial, x );
}

float nsect( float a, float b, const float eps_x )
{
    float fa = f( a );
    float fb = f( b );
    if ( fa == 0 ) return a;
    else if ( fb == 0 ) return b;
    else if ( fa * fb > 0 ) return 0;

    float x[NSECT];
    float fx[NSECT];

    while ( b - a > eps_x )
    {   
        x[0] = a;
        if ( ( fx[0] = f( x[0] ) ) == 0 ) return x[0];

        int found = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < NSECT - 1; i++ )
        {
            x[i + 1] = a + ( b - a ) * (float)( i + 1 ) / NSECT;
            if ( ( fx[i + 1] = f( x[i + 1] ) ) == 0 )
                return x[i + 1];
            else if ( fx[i] * fx[i + 1] < 0 )
            {
                a = x[i];
                b = x[i + 1];
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( !found )
            a = x[NSECT - 1]; 

    }

    return ( a + b ) * 0.5f;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    struct timeval t0, t1;
    float *polys = malloc( COUNT * sizeof( float ) * N );
    float *p = polys;
    for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT * N; i++ )
        scanf( "%f", p++ ); 

    float xsum = 0; // So the code isn't optimized when we don't print the roots
    p = polys;
    gettimeofday( &t0, NULL );
    for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++, p += N )
    {
        memcpy( polynomial, p, N * sizeof( float ) );
        float x = nsect( -100, 100, 1e-3 );
        xsum += x;

        #ifdef PRINT_ROOTS
            fprintf( stderr, "%f\n", x );
        #endif
    }
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );

    fprintf( stderr, "xsum: %f\n", xsum );
    printf( "%f ms\n", ( ( t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec ) * 1e6 + ( t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec ) ) * 1e-3 );
    free( polys );
}
```

EDIT: This is the command I used to compile the code: `clang -O3 -o nsect nsect.c -Wall -DCOUNT=5000000 -DNSECT=? -funroll-loops`.
I ran everything on i7-8700k.

I decided to test the algorithm performance for different *N* values. The test consists of measuring time needed to find any root in range (-100;100) for each of 5,000,000 polynomials of degree 5. The polynomials are randomly generated and have real coefficients ranging from -5 to 5. The polynomial values are calculated using Horner's method.

These are results I got from running the code 10 times for each *N* (x=*N*, y=time [ms]):
[image]

My understanding of the worst case performance here is that the amount of work to be done in the main while loop is proportional to *N*. The main loop needs *log<sub>N</sub>(C)* (where *C > 1* is a constant - ratio of initial search range to requested accuracy) iterations to complete. This yields following equation:

[image: Equation]

The plot looks very similar to the violet curve I used above to roughly match the data:
[image]

Now, I have some (hopefully correct) conclusions and questions:

- Firstly, is my approach valid at all?
- Does the function I came up with really describe the relation between  number of operations and *N*?
- I think this is the most interesting one - I'm wondering what causes such significant difference between *N=2* and all the others? I consistently get this pattern for all my test data.

Moreover:

- That function has minimum in *e≈2.718...*, which is closer to 3 than to 2. Also, *f(3) < f(2)* holds. Given that the equation I came up with is correct, I think that would imply that trisection method may actually be more efficient than bisection. It seems a bit counter intuitive, but the measurements seem to acknowledge that. Is this right?
- If so, why does trisection method seem to be so unpopular compared to bisection?

Thank you

Comment: These root solvers are essentially, after averaging over many random functions and scaling the initial interval to have length 1, listing the digits of a number (the root to which they are converging) in base N. The numeric system that is most efficient [is the one of base 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446664/what-is-the-most-efficient-numerical-base-system).

Comment: @conditionalMethod that's actually pretty interesting fact. Thank you

Comment: A bisection algorithm is structurally very simple, just like bubblesort among the sort algorithms. For a trisection implementation you need at least two branchings to select the next interval. If you are that concerned about the performance of bisection, a more striking improvement is obtained by selecting the midpoint using the function values as the secant root etc., like in regula falsi and its variants, then Dekker's method and the widely used Brent's method.

Comment: @LutzL I'm aware that better methods exists. I was just curious of the influence of the N value on the performance and was just playing around until I couldn't really explain the N=2 case. Then I decided to ask a question here :)

Comment: @conditionalMethod: That "economy" metric (radix * length of digit-string needed) seems made-up in a way that just happens to match the time-complexity of this task.  Refining the accuracy of a root involves calculations with a serial dependency, but the analogy to div / rem to produce a digits breaks down because integer division doesn't take longer with higher divisors, it takes near constant time with any non-power-of-2 divisor, or much less with any power of 2.  (On real HW anyway).

Comment: And here we can increase the instruction-level parallelism by using larger N.  Although we possible bottleneck on division throughput (not fully pipelined) for non-power-of-2 `NSECT` because the code uses `... / NSECT` instead of `... * (1.0f / NSECT)`.  The OP doesn't mention using `-ffast-math` which would allow the compiler to use a reciprocal even if it's not exactly representable.  In fact they don't mention any optimization options at all...  Or what compiler + hardware they tested on.

Comment: If compiling for x86 or other ISAs with SIMD, using NSECT=5 would allow easy vectorization, evaluation the polynomial for 4 elements in parallel, but IDK how easily a compiler would spot that from this source code.  Probably not because of the conditional branch inside the loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes I specified the build command in the comment at the top of the source code. It's not really visible there - sorry for that. I used `clang` compiler and `-O3` optimization. I didn't, however, try using `-ffast-math` and enabling vectorization. My CPU is i7-8700k.

Comment: `clang -O3` *does* enable auto-vectorization.  But yeah, `-ffast-math` may help.  Also worth using `-march=native` to let it use AVX, FMA, and everything else your CPU supports.  FMA is great for Horner's rule.

Comment: The overall results still seem strange. If you do compute the full function table (which you do not), then (N-1) evaluations result in a reduction in the interval by a factor of $N$, so that to get to a given final interval length requires C*(N-1)/log(N) function evaluations. However, if you evaluate the function table in the manner of a binary search, only evaluating the function values you actually need, you should regain asymptotically the characteristics of the bisection method. ...

Comment: ... The exception is the `N=3` case, where you have to compare `2/log(3)=1.820478` to the bisections `1/log(2)=2/log(4)=1.442695` (in contrast to the `N/log(N)` formula where trisection `3/log(3)=6/log(9)` is smaller than bisection `2/log(2)=6/log(8)`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The time that this algorithm will take to locate a random number to a given precision is proportional to the number of iterations of the `while` times the average time that each `for` loop will take to locate the subinterval with the sign change. The precision determines a certain maximum number `n` of numbers in base N that are representable. Each loop of the `for` determines one of those digits. At worst each time there will be a number proportional to N of loops of that `for` to locate the digit in base N. Therefore, the algorithm takes a time proportional to the number of ...

Comment: ... digits ln(n)/ln(N) times N. The n is fixed. Now minimize N/ln(N).

Comment: The result is rather trivial, actually, in terms of complexity analysis. It is just multiplying the length of each of the two nested loops. The rest is just understanding what writing a number in base N is. The `while` has length equal to the number of digits that the tolerance `eps_x` allows to represent in base N, and the `for` will take (proportional to ) N iterations in the worst case.

Comment: I ran the test once again, this time with `-ffast-math` and `-march=native`: https://imgur.com/a/othkCXk. The times are much better now, especially thanks to `-ffast-math`. The shape of the curve, however, still remains the same. I'd even say that the gap between N=2 and N=3 is more visible now. `(N-1)/log N` and `N/log N` functions don't seem to explain that, because they don't change that violently between 2 and 3. Do you see any mathematical or technical reasons for this behavior?

Comment: There is nothing else to explain. Run all your tests with a function that has its only root close enough to the right end of the interval. That is where those algorithms will do worst. For that case we have already given you the counting of the number of iterations. Everything else is just bad methodology, and poor understanding.

Comment: Why this: `if ( ( fx[i + 1] = f( x[i + 1] ) ) == 0 )` ?

Comment: In the inner loop you are recomputing `fa == f(x[0])` and possibly `fb == f(x[NSECT])`. This has a massive influcence on the runtime in the bisection and trisection cases, not so much in the higher divisions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It checks if f(x) is 0. It's very unlikely, but can happen and would result in root being missed.

Comment: @LutzL I didn't realize how huge the difference caused by that can be. I optimized the code, so it reuses f(x) values from previous iterations and N=2 is now comparable to all the others. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Jacajack: ouch, the assignment embedded in the test makes it so unreadable ! Personally, I avoid the tests for "early" zeroes because they just add overhead in 99.999% of the cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It makes sense, and I was thinking about doing something about it, but I also felt somewhat uncomfortable with having the zero test all the way at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am commenting on the general question, not on your particular code, which I don't fully understand.

Assuming that there is a single root known to be in an interval of length L and the desired accuracy is ε, you will need log(L/ε)/log(N) subdivision stages. Every subdivision stage requires N-1 evaluations of the function (not N), to tell which subinterval among N contains the root.

Hence, neglecting overhead, the total cost is proportional to (N-1)/log(N). The values of this ratio are, starting from N=2:

```
1.44, 1.82, 2.16, 2.49, 2.79...
```

and higher.

Hence the theoretical optimum is with N=2. This is why trisection is not used.

Comment: I optimized the code a bit, and there's no longer a spike for N=2. Now (N-1)/log(N)  seems to be the right way to describe the complexity indeed. Thank you for your explanation